# Page Number in Cell (without macro/VBA)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xls

I am looking for a solution to display the print page in a cell within excel. But I need to do this without a macro or VBA.

So far I have not found a solution. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
=Concatenate("Page ", INT(Row()/"No of Rows in Page")+1, " of ","PageCount")
```

replace "No of Rows in Page" with the number of rows you want in each page, and replace "PageCount" with the total page numbers.

example:

```
=CONCATENATE("Page ",INT(ROW()/5)+1, " of ",12)
```

every 5 row and total number of 12 pages.

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work dynamically as for print pages. Would a few rows be hidden by a filter, it would not return the actual print page.

Comment: Can you just use a header or footer?

Comment: @314UnreadEmails i don't understand your question, please provide more clarification + example

Comment: Right click on the ribbon and select "customize the ribbon". In the "choose commands from" drop down box select "all commands". Scroll down to "header and footer" add this command to a custom group on your ribbon. Click OK. Go to this group which is now on your ribbon and select "header & footer". In the drop down box for either header or footer or both, select the data you want to show. Click ok and check out the print preview to see what it will look like.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is very old, but I've been searching for a while now for a viable option to solve this issue and I think I found something that works for me. This is a little unorthodox and certainly not very dynamic, but it relies on the fact that Excel allows the header to overlap the cell contents.

If you put a header in your sheet with the following: `Page  &[Page]  of  &[Pages]` and line it up with the cell in your document where you want the page number, you can have it print with the correct page number and page count in your cell.

**NOTE: This does not actually display the page number in the cell. It only appears to be in the cell when you print.**

Technically this does not actually answer your question, as written, but I believe it answers the intent of the question.

The page numbers may not appear to line up when looking at the Page Layout View. You have to look at your print preview to make sure they print in the correct place. Also, be sure you consider the fact that it may move depending on which printer you use.

**Page Layout View**
[image: Page Layout View]

**Printed Page**
[image: Printed Page]

Answer (score 0):

I have used the ormula given by Marcel and it works:

```
=CONCATENATE("Page ",INT(ROW()/5)+1, " of ",12)
```

I have made only one change. Instead of `+1`, I Added Cell No. and added the required number in cell. i.e.,

```
=CONCATENATE("  ",INT(ROW()/9)+Formula!A1, " of ",500)
```

And then, in the Formula sheet cell no A1, I added the required serial number.

It works.

[image]